# simple video decoding in Java / Scala

Tags: java, scala, video, decoding

Is there an easy way to decode video in java/scala?

I need just the frames and have to do some computations with them. No need to be fast or real time.

I tried processing which worked but not nice and i wasn't able to embedded it in my project. I saw also jmf but it seams to be no longer maintained since 2004.

Comment: In the moment it's an AVI with DivX. But if needed we should be able to change the container/codec. But it have to be a compressed format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) or [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/) (which tried to pick up where JMF left off, but looks semi-dead).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'FrameGrab' class from JCodec (http://jcodec.org).
Right now it supports MP4 ( ISO BMF, QuickTime ) file format with AVC ( H.264 ) video inside.
For just one frame

```
int frameNumber = 150;
BufferedImage frame = FrameGrab.getFrame(new File("filename.mp4"), frameNumber);
ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("frame_150.png"));
```

JCodec is available in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcodec</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

or as a download on it's web site.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get frames from a video file compressed to any format supported by FFMpeg using [velvet-video](https://github.com/zakgof/velvet-video):

```
IVideoLib lib = new FFMpegVideoLib();
IDemuxer demuxer = lib.demuxer(new File("path-to-video-file"));
while(demuxer.nextPacket(frame -> {
    BufferedImage image = frame.image();
    // You get frames as BufferedImages here
}, null));
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of velvet-video.